# Refs is null in componentWillReceiveProps for parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent component:

```
test = () => {
    var childRef = this.childReference;
}
render() {
    return (
        <Child ref={child => this.childReference = child} test={this.test}/>
    );
}
```

Child component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.props.test();
    //Same result with nextProps.test();
}
```

`this.childReference` is null.
Interestingly the refs on the child component work fine.

Why is this and is their a work around?

Comment: What do you mean by the ref works fine on the child component?

Comment: You are passing a `test` prop of `this.test` to `Child`. Since `this.test` doesn't change, `nextProps.test()` will of course have the same result as `this.props.test()`. The ref isn't set until after the component has mounted, and even then, the `test` prop passed to `Child` will remain unchanged. What exactly are you trying to do with the ref?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?